# Переходя по адресу реального домена, попадаю на локальный хост

Tags: apache, dns

По весне баловался с виртуальными хостами одного проекта. Теперь пробую зайти на реальный домен `***.ru` и у меня идёт перенаправление на виртуальный хост в папку локального сервера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помню, что изменял файлы в папке `/etc`.

Как это устранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вероятно, это был файл [`/etc/hosts`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts).

найдите, удалите или закомментруйте (символ `#` в начале строки) ненужное сейчас сопоставление между ip-адресом и доменным именем, которое выглядит, скорее всего, примерно так (используя вашу терминологию):

```
127.0.0.1 ***.ru
```

ip-адрес может быть, конечно, и другим, закреплённым за любым из сетевых интерфейсов вашего компьютера.

---

другая возможная причина описанного поведения — возможно, доменное имя резолвится в ip-адрес из сети `127/8`, например, в тот же `127.0.0.1`.

проверить это можно с помощью любой из программ для резолвинга, позволяющей указать (на всякий случай) и *nameserver* (например, «гугловский» `8.8.8.8` или `8.8.4.4`), которая найдётся в вашей системе:

```
$ host domain.ru 8.8.8.8
$ nslookup domain.ru 8.8.8.8
$ dig @8.8.8.8 domain.ru
```

Comment: Я тоже сначала туда полез, но там находится только данное содержимое: 
127.0.0.1       localhost

Comment: я исходил из предположения, что отображается страница, действительно генерируемая на вашей машине. вы уверены в этом? кстати, а что у вас находится в `/etc/resolv.conf`? не собственный ли *nameserver* там прописан?

Comment: В /etc/resolv.conf  содержится следующий код: 
`domain Dlink
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.1`

Comment: а что насчёт первого вопроса? по поводу того, как вы определяете, что это именно ваша машина генерирует страницу с текстом «it really works…»

Comment: это 100% на моей локальной машине, так как при изменении файла index.html в папке с сайтами, содержимое страницы  ***.ru меняется.

Comment: а домен совсем секретный? дело в том, что доменное имя вполне «законно» может резолвиться в адрес из сети `127/8`. например: http://benjamin.barak.in

Comment: домен higo.ru
Он куплен и планируется под проект. На другом компьютере выдает ошибку, так как не привязан к хостингу. Уже голову сломал с этим

Comment: так и есть — это имя резолвится в ip-адрес 127.0.0.1

Comment: Александр, получается, что если я прикручу хостинг и залью содержимое сайта, то он будет успешно отображаться?

Comment: по этому адресу каждый пользователь интернета увидит то, что возвращает *его* локальный http-сервер. а т.к. у подавляющего большинства пользователей такого сервера на локальной машине нет, они получат от браузера сообщение, что он не может соединиться с сервером.

Comment: чтобы это доменное имя резолвилось в нужный вам ip-адрес, надо изменить dns-запись для этого имени. часто регистраторы доменных имён предлагают бесплатно (или за небольшую плату) обслуживать dns-записи домена прямо у них же. и даже какой-нибудь веб-интерфейс («панель управления») для этого предоставляют.

Comment: Александр, я перевёл dns-адреса на адреса своего хостера. Но парадокс в том, что у всех открывается этот сайт (higo.ru), а у меня когда как. То открывается, то пропадает и пишет в браузере ошибку: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. Видимо, проблема у меня на локальной машине.

Comment: вы изменили информацию о домене, указав дргугие сервера имён. пока не истечёт ttl, dns-серверы будут возвращать закэшированную информацию. подождите два часа, пока не истечёт ttl для soa вашего домена — судя по ответу от ns1.agava.ru, он был установлен в два часа.

Answer (score 0):

Файл `/etc/hosts`. Уберите из него строчку вида

```
127.0.0.1     ***.ru
```

Comment: Я тоже сначала туда полез, но там находится только данное содержимое: 
127.0.0.1       localhost

Comment: А если локальный кэш днс почистить: dscacheutil -flushcache

Comment: кэш почистил, сервер перезагрузил - результат остался тем же

Comment: То есть у вас апач запущен? А если в его настройках удалить виртуальный хост относящийся к данному сайту и перезапустить его снова?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду файл с конфигурацией \etc\apache2\httpd.conf? в нём нет упоминаний про мой домен

Comment: Да. В этом файле возможно есть команды Include подключающие другие *.conf файлы. Проверьте на всякий случай.

Comment: Увы, нет никаких ссылок на другие файлы.